# Create own "insert clip" macro like "add image sequence" in kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive, script

I would like to write an own script/macro/program/command similar to the "add image sequence" command. The main purpose is to insert portrait mode photos into the timeline, which are displayed on a side-by-side layout (two photos on one slide).

Inserting this layout into the timeline by mouse and keyboard is quite a mess, though possible, so I think this could be automated in any way.

Is this at all possible, and if so, where can I find additional information on scripting kdenlive?

EDIT: If I could not describe my idea very well, see [this short video clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnaoOrQNfBI) on Youtube.